# Color duplicates in knime report

Tags: birt, knime

In **KNIME REPORT VIEWER**, we colour the data conditional based with help of highlights tab on bottom pane.

**My Question**
For example there is a data with me,
Student marks of a particular subject,
I want to mark the students with a particular condition say,subject science with student marks of 95 with BLUE.

Is there any condition like finding the duplicate values and colour them? Or any other approach? 
Can anyone help me out please.

Comment: For me it is not clear what is your problem. I assume you can specify the coloring based on a column and you want a column which has a unique value for the duplicate columns and the same value for unique values. To achieve this, you need to GroupBy to find the duplicate values, filter out those that are unique (count = 1) and join back the count (but first you might want to combine the keys, which will be the id of each duplicate). HTH

Comment: Found the solution! Sorry for not being clear in my question @Gabor Bakos, thanks for you help!  BIRT REPORT VIEWER help me for conditional formatting, with its inbuilt options.

Comment: In that case you should add the solution as an answer.

Comment: My solution :  My task to highlight the particular data in particular column. 
BIRT REPORT VIEWER helped me to solution. After creating data set views,
I dragged them to layout and select a column to highlight the data. 
Down to pane there will be column "highlight".
Select add and select the column in condition & value corresponding to it, to highlight it. 
You can select a colour, font style etc. to highlight your required data and then run the BIRT report.
@Gabar Bakos. Hope this would be helpful to other even.